# why sorted() in python didn't accept positional arguments?

Tags: python, sorting

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
def func(x):
   return x**x

b=sorted(a,func)
```

this line always gives a error->

> TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 2

in fact the syntax of sorted is `sorted(iterable,key,reverse)`, in which `key` and `reverse` are optional, so according to this, second parameter i pass must go with `key`.

and when i def my own func

```
def func2(x,y=4,z=10):
    print(x,y,z)
func2(100,200)--->output-->>100 200 10
```

here 200 automatically passed as `y` argument for `func2`. How does this work?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in the first example? sort by the item squared? what output do you expect?

Comment: From the documentation: **Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.**

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: `b = sorted(a, key=func)` works but it won't do much in this case

Comment: @TenaciousB it was just an example nothing more.
to get my ques clear in reader mind...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to @user4815162342's answer,
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted),

```py
sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

Notice the `*` between `iterable` and `key` parameter.  That is the python syntax for specifying that
every parameter after `*` **must** be specified as *keyword arguments*.

So your custom function should be defined as the following to apply the similar implementation:

```py
def func2(x, *, y=4, z=10):
    print(x, y, z)

func2(100, 200)
```

> TypeError: func2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 8):

> why sorted() in python doesn't accept positional arguments?

Because `sorted` used to accept positional arguments in Python 2, but the second argument was the *comparison* function, not the *key* function as it is now. Python 3 dropped support for comparison function in `list.sort` and `sorted` was modified accordingly. It was deemed too confusing to silently change the *meaning* of a poositional argument, so the devs decided to completely forbid positional arguments (except for the very first argument, the iterable to sort), and require keyword arguments for everything else.

The intention is for unmodified Python 2 code that calls `sorted(sequence, function)` to fail fast in Python 3, instead of attempting to call the comparison function as a key function, calling it with an incorrect number of arguments. This prevents confusion that might ensue if the comparison function happened to accept a variable number of arguments, or if the sequence were empty so the sort happened to "work" for some inputs.

Likewise, `sorted(sequence, cmp=function)` fails early due to `cmp` having been removed. `sorted(sequence, key=function)` works as intended in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Is there a PEP or something that covers this?

Comment: @Phillyclause89 I'm not aware of one. While there are _some_ PEPs that cover Python 3 (their numbers begin with 3000), it seems that there was a time when many decisions were made on mailing lists without a well-defined procedure.  Changes to `list.sort` and `sorted` appear to fall into that category.